# Es necesario agregar [301] en htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Una consulta relacionada a url amigables.

Estoy diseñando un sitio desde 0 en php y me preguntaba si es necesario agregar el [301] en la linea de Rewriterule como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^rubro/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).php rubro.php?id=$1 [301]
```

De ser así, ¿en qué caso es mejor utilizarlo?

Comment: si lo vas a mover permanentemente a otro domain si!

Comment: Disculpame no te entiendo, me especificarias mejor. saludos.

Comment: te adjunto una pagina de los codigos [codigo de estado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP)

Comment: por ejemplo yo estoy creado la web y todavia no esta lanzada, entonces por lo que me comentas deberia dejarlo sin el 301 y de esta forma es mejor para el seo. Es asi?. Saludos.

Comment: Si esta en desarrollo agrega un index de temporalmente en mantenimiento o algo asi ya que 301 es solo una redireccion a otro lugar

Comment: ok, pero una vez lanzado, sacaria ese 301, verdad?.

Comment: Disculpame nuevamente y si agrego estas lineas son necesarias para mi codigo htaccess.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d